# How to select only one row based on col / result in SQL

Tags: sql

Here are my tables:

Table **Logs**:

```
    Id   LogCode
   ---------------
    1    111
    2    222
    3    333
    4    444
    5    555
```

Table **LogsDetails1**:

```
Id LogCode StartTime            EndTime                 NQCode
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1  111     06/01/2019 15:00:00  06/01/2019 15:07:00     14
```

Table **LogsDetails2**:

```
Id LogCode StartTime            EndTime                 NQCode
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1  333     06/03/2019 16:00:00  06/03/2019 16:09:00     15
```

I want all records from table `Logs` with matching `Logdetails1` and `Logdetails2`.

That's why I used a left join.

Result is like this

```
logId LogCode DetailsLogCode StartTime            EndTime              NQCode
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------    
1     111     111            06/01/2019 15:00:00  06/01/2019 15:07:00     14 
1     111       0                       
2     222       0
3     333       0
3     333     333          06/03/2019 16:00:00  06/03/2019 16:09:00     15
4     444       0
5     555       0
```

I want to fetch only one record out of two when same logscode present more than one, one with proper Detailslogcode other with 0. I want to choose record with proper value. There are many more columns present Logsdetail table. I don't want apply condition on startdate, enddate. These col may not present some time depending on interface condition.

I want to apply con on logscode only. If I applied max on Logsdeails, it will get that value. That might give me wrong details. I don't want for column, want for entire row.

Like

```
1     111     111            06/01/2019 15:00:00  06/01/2019 15:07:00     14 
1      111     0
```

I want show first one record where both LogCode and DetailsLogCode present not second one.

When there is no match, show that.

I want output like this:

```
logId LogCode DetailsLogCode StartTime            EndTime              NQCode
------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
1       111     111           06/01/2019 15:00:00  06/01/2019 15:07:00     14                 
2       222       0
3       333     333           06/03/2019 16:00:00  06/03/2019 16:09:00     15
4       444       0
5       555       0
```

Comment: Please show your queries.

Comment: Isn't there a case where both logdetails tables contain the same logcode? In that case do you want both rows?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your attempts were, but hope that the following query will give you a couple of ideas.

What is happening here is conditional grouping by `DetailsLogCode`. I have also provided a `count` for reference. Should you need the latest log inside a group with valid `DetailsLogCode`, you can achieve that by selecting max(StartTime).

```
SELECT logId, LogCode, DetailsLogCode, StartTime, EndTime, NQCode, count(*) FROM (SELECT 
  logId, LogCode, DetailsLogCode, StartTime, EndTime, NQCode
FROM LogsDetails1
  JOIN Logs on Logs.Id = LogsDetails1.logId
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  logId, LogCode as LogCode, DetailsLogCode, StartTime, EndTime, NQCode
FROM LogsDetails2
  JOIN Logs on Logs.Id = LogsDetails2.logId) A
  GROUP BY DetailsLogCode, CASE WHEN DetailsLogCode = 0 THEN 1 END
ORDER BY logId;
```

You can use [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/85b602/1) SQL fiddle as a playground.